# How do I document a c# dll

Tags: c#, class, dll, attributes

How do I write a class so that property and method descriptions are visible to people referencing the dll in other projects?

```
    [Description("My age in years attribute")]
    public int Age
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
    /// <summary>
    /// My age in years attribute
    /// </summary>
    public int Age
    {
        get { return 0; }
        set { }
    }
```

Comment: Your second one *does* work for me.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the xml comments work for me.

Comment: The second example works if the project referencing the class is within the same solution. I am compiling the class as a dll and referencing this DLL.  The DLL doesn't seem to preserve any of the attribute or summary information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Visual Studio:

> Project -> Properties -> Build -> Check "XML Documentation File".

For further details, see [XML Comments Let You Build Documentation Directly From Your Visual Studio .NET Source Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx).

Comment: Does this mean I need to distribute the XML with the DLL and reference them both?  Is there any way I can just have all the information in the DLL?

Comment: No, the XML comments are not part of any metadata in the assembly.

Comment: @James: You could embed the output XML file as a resource in the DLL. But why would you want to do this? There is already a perfectly standard way of shipping the XML comments with the DLL. Visual Studio integrates nicely with the XML files that are output by the process described above.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I'm working on an in house project so my methods are limited. Restricting things to a standalone DLL with embedded XML makes things more manageable

Comment: @James: Okay; fair enough. Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The description provided in `DescriptionAttribute` is visible in Property Grid for sure and it has nothing to do with code editor.

For XML comments to be available, you have to [generate an XML documentation file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4sa0ak0(VS.80).aspx) and ship it with your assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Did you build the `XML documentation file` for your second case?

> Project properties -> Build -> [Output] XML Documentation file

Answer (score 1):

The second should work (summary), be sure to select in the project Properties (Build -> Output ) XML Documentation File.